# Capitalise every character after certain character

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a string eg. String-aa. I want to be able to capitalise every letter after the "-". Is there a straightforward was of achieving this?

I am aware of .capitalize however dont know how to implement for this particular requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of block form of `gsub`

```
"String-aa-bbbb".gsub(/-\w+/){|e| e.upcase}
#=> "String-AA-BBBB"
```

The above code will capture a letter followed by `-` and will capitalize it

Comment: Thanks but what I want is for String-aa to convert to String-AA so every character after - is capitalised.

Comment: Then select `\w+`